# How can I run a network through 200' of forest?

Tags: networking

Suppose I have a telephone line with DSL at point A, and a computer at point B. A and B are in the woods, and about 200' apart.  How should I connect them?

I'm excluding burying wires, as B is somewhat temporary and mobile.

Options I've considered:

1. DSL Modem + Wi-Fi Access Point at A. Wireless through the woods.
2. DSL Modem at A. Run ethernet through the woods to B.
3. Run telephone line from A to B. DSL Modem at B.

Our climate consists of a looooong, damp, mild winter and a short, dry, mild summer.

Comment: Go with Wi-Fi, my son. 802.11b should have the distance, though the speed is lacking.

Comment: Hardly through the woods you can use wifi. What about ethernet over power lines?

Answer (score 7):

Wi-fi with directional antennas.

Comment: Assuming you have LOS

Answer (score 4):

For 200' look at a pre-made fiber pair (fairly armored) and some fiber-Ethernet converters,.

will eat 200' for breakfast, and your Ethernet won't care.

I'm suggesting fiber because 60M is a fairly long Ethernet run.

There is wifi-like equipment 5.4Ghz which  might work a lot better than 2.4GHz, as the 2.4GHz hates moisture and humidity .

Answer (score 1):

If you are a 'home-brew' kinda guy, try the 'Can'tenna:
http://www.mikestechblog.com/joomla/networking-section/wifi-wireless-category/58-extend-wireless-wifi-network-building-24-ghz-cantenna.html

http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/wlg/448

Which give extra directional gain over wifi.

Answer (score 0):

For 200' you can easily use a wireless bridge, most commercial AP's support this. We use these to bring internet to our loading yard 1/2 mile away from our MDF.